# How can a 32-bit structure represent a negative 64-bit value?

Tags: c, numbers, structure

In a 32-bit C programming environment without any built-in native 64-bit support, but some parts of the operating system API's do support 64-bit numbers, I have to represent a negative value (range -8192 upto and including -1). Presumably I have to do the maths myself.

```
typedef struct _LONGLONG {ULONG lo;LONG hi} LONGLONG;
LONGLONG x;
```

How can I assign such a negative value to x.lo and x.hi, and (less important) perhaps how can I verify it's the right number?

I've read about "What's wrong with quadpart?", but apparently there's no such thing available.

Comment: x.hi is `LONG`, so it supports negative numbers. Also, you don't need 64bit for the range [-8192, -1].

Comment: `32-bit C programming environment without any built-in native 64-bit` Could you share what "environment" is that? What compiler are you using? `some parts of the operating system API's` Which parts? What parts? What API are you using? What operating system are you using? Could you be more specific? If your OS supports 64-bit, would be strange if userapps wouldn't. `I have to represent a negative value` "Represent" in what way? "How" are negative numbers represented in your "environment"? (nervously looks at [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement))

Comment: FWIW: an unsual environment of the 90s and 00s, not aware of __int64's, and so on. The generic answer helped, BTW. Later a few 64-bit functions were added, and the app already does test if the user has such an OS upgrade or newer version installed. It's nothing special, so perhaps it's a bit like 32-bit version of Windows supporting huge files by using a LARGE_INTEGER? But without some Quadpart nor __int64, or whatever people refered to nowadays.

Comment: I don't need 64 bits for the range indeed, but the API does. I just mentioned the range to indicate that 2 bytes ought to be enought, so there are no overflowing bits involved (while keeping in mind that I had no clue how easy the answer would be).

Answer (score 1):

Bits represent values only according to some type scheme. The question does not state what scheme is used to make the bits in `lo` and `hi` represent values. For the purposes of this answer, we will suppose:

- `LONG hi` is a 32-bit two’s complement integer.
- `ULONG lo` is a 32-bit unsigned integer.
- The API using this `LONGLONG` structure interprets `lo` and `hi` as a 64-bit two’s complement number formed with the bits of `hi` as the high 32 bits of the 64-bit number and the bits of `low` as the low 32 bits.

In this case, if `n` is a value in [−8192, −1], the upper 32 bits of a 64-bit two’s complement representation are all ones, and the lower 32 bits are the same as the 32 bits of a 32-bit two’s complement representation of `n`. Therefore, the desired bit patterns of the `LONGLONG x` can be set with:

```
x.hi = -1;
x.lo = n;
```

Note that, since `x.lo` is unsigned, the assignment `x.lo = n` will convert the signed `n` to unsigned. This conversion will be done by wrapping modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, and the resulting 32-bit unsigned value for `x.lo` has the same bit pattern as the 32-bit two’s complement value for `n`, so the desired result is achieved.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent, and clear. The real N is positive, but that's easy to fix then (n*=-1; or x.lo=0;x.lo-=n;). Now I've also verified the results by using Rexx ("rexx rexxtry say X2B(D2X(-8192,32))").